# Resolving Some Issues with Selecting Android Platforms and Documentation, Etc

Tags: android

I'm sure these are noobie questions, but I'd like to take care of these issues and such before I fully dive into the development process and literature that I have on hand for the Android OS. Okay, so, as per the Android programming book I have (the one by the Deitels and Morgano), aside from selecting for installation the latest revision of the Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools, the SDK platforms for the 2.2, 2.3.3, 3.0, 3.1, and 3.2, I need to install the Documentation for Android SDK, API 13, revision 1. On the Android SDK Manager that I have on my laptop, under the Android 4.0.3, there's the 'Documentation for Android SDK'. However, it's the API 15, revision 1 version. I'm a bit confused, as, for one thing, isn't the Android 4.0.3 the Ice Cream Sandwich version of the OS? I'm just wondering if this documentation is supposed to work with all earlier versions of the OS or just with the 4.0. If it's the latter, then does the fact that it falls under the Android 4.0.3 directory merely refer to it's being the latest documentation for the Android SDK, in general or just for the Ice Cream Sandwich? In the screen shot from the book, there's a combined Android SDK and AVD manager, which is different from what I'm seeing, due to the new updates to Eclipse and Android. Also, the documentation and the SDK Platforms for all the versions that the book covers are shown under the 'Android Repository' which doesn't show up in the version I have running on my laptop. My final question (for now) is: Do I just need the SDK Platforms or do I also need to install everything that falls under the various API directories (e.g. samples for SDK, Google API's etc.)? Thanks in advance for any and all help.

See ya on the flipside,

Cyon Corell

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just wondering if this documentation is supposed to work with all earlier versions of the OS or just with the 4.0.

The documentation highlights when various classes and methods were added, in terms of their API levels.

> In the screen shot from the book, there's a combined Android SDK and AVD manager, which is different from what I'm seeing, due to the new updates to Eclipse and Android.

Your book is slightly out of date. The SDK Manager and AVD Manager were split into separate windows a couple of months ago.

> Do I just need the SDK Platforms or do I also need to install everything that falls under the various API directories (e.g. samples for SDK, Google API's etc.)?

You will want the Google APIs, as they give you access to Google Maps. Even if you do not plan on using Google Maps in your project, it is better if you test with emulators that have Google Maps, as they are incrementally closer to what most users have.

Whether you want the samples is up to you.

Comment: So, the documentation (under the Android 4.0.3 directory) will work for all the previous versions of the OS?

Comment: @CyonCorell: So long as you pay attention to the API levels noted in the documentation itself, yes.